# NSString drawInRect: and drop shadows on iOS

Tags: ios, opengl-es, core-graphics

I'm using `[NSString drawInRect:]` to draw text to a texture and everything works fine until I add drop shadows.  They appear correctly, but are often clipped by the rect I'm drawing to.

The issue is that `[NSString sizeWithFont:]` doesn't know about the drop shadows since they are applied via `CGContextSetShadowWithColor(...)`.

Here is the code I'm using (fluff removed):

```
CGSize dim = [theString sizeWithFont:uifont];

...

CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0f, dim.height);
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0f, -1.0f);
CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, CGSizeMake(dropOffset.x, dropOffset.y), dropBlur, dropColorRef);

...

[theString drawInRect:dim withFont:uifont lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap alignment:align];
```

I've tried expanding `dim` to take the drop shadow and blur into account and that mostly works, but sometimes the expanded rect causes the line to be wrapped completely different due to the extra space that was added.

Is there a better way to be finding the size of the texture/rect needed to draw to (or to draw the string) than I'm using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to keep track of two different rects.

1. The rect that will contain the text, which you pass to `-[NSString drawInRect:]`.  Call this `stringBounds`.
2. The expanded/offset rect that contains the shadow. Call this `shadowBounds`.

Make your texture the size of `shadowBounds`.

When you draw the text, you'll need to translate by `shadowBounds.origin - stringBounds.origin`. (Or possibly the reverse -- it depends on exactly what you do, in which order. You'll know it when you get it.)

Then do `[theString drawInRect:stringBounds ...]`.

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but when I do the `[theString drawInRect:stringBounds ...]` the string is translated correctly, but the shadow is clipped even if the context is larger.   It's like the whole string (text+shadow) is clipped by stringBounds.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `-[NSString drawInRect:...]` doesn't clip. I bet you are getting the offset wrong, or the expanded rect size wrong, and making your shadow go outside the bitmap context. To debug, try just filling your whole context with one color, then fill a rect in another color rather than drawing the text -- it should be obvious if it's in the right place or not.

Comment: OK, I finally figured out what was tripping me up.  Let's say you have a -5 x drop shadow.  When you draw the text, 0 is the left edge of the drop shadow, not the text.  I was assuming that 0 always remained linked to the text, but it's the edge if everything that is drawn.