# Shadow effect for NSString

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, nsstring, shadow

I want to apply shadow effect to text of type NSString.
Though I understand how to apply shadow effect to UILabel and other view elements,
I can't figure out a way of adding shadow effect to text.

I am currently drawing text as follows:

```
NSString *text = @"Hello";
[text drawAtPoint:point width withFont:font minFontSize:22.0f actualFontSize:&actualFontSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeTailTruncation baselineAdjustment:UIBaselineAdjustmentAlignBaselines];
```

I would really appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: You can find your answer in this post: [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10164808/nsstring-drawinrect-and-drop-shadows-on-ios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `CGContextSetShadow()` for adding shadow to text

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect 
{
NSString *string = @"Hello World!";

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetShadow(context, CGSizeMake(20.0f, 20.0f), 10.0f);

[string drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(100.0f, 100.0f) withFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:36.0f]];
}
```